# Turning an HTML select element into a tree with submenus

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, treeview, menu

I want to have a select element have a submenus in a tree fashion.

I want it to be something like this:

[image]
<sub>(source: [colinear.com](http://www.colinear.com/rmenu.gif))</sub>

Is there a jQuery plugin that can turn a select element into this kind of thing?

Comment: Normally this is done with an `<ol>` or `<ul>` with `<li> and nested `<ol>`/`<ul>` 's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the [tree plug-ins](http://plugins.jquery.com/search/node/tree+type%3Aproject_project) listed on the jquery site.  [Mb.menu](http://pupunzi.com/#mb.components/mb._menu/menu.html) looks like a good fit.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to do what you want with a select element, how will the plugin work out the submenus?

Here is one that uses ul/li's [jQuery Menu](http://apycom.com/menus/1-white-smoke.html)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this works, but here's a link that might be helpful.

http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=6294