# multi-level accordion menu

Tags: asp.net, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I am looking for multi-level accordion menu (drill down to few levels deeper) (expand and collapsible) for my website. Is there a sample anywhere I can use? Thanks in advance.

it will be nice if I can dock it to the left by clicking on an icon and slide back when I click on the icon again.

Something like this:

```
menu1
  menu2
    menu3
    menu4
  menu5
    menu6
menu7
  menu8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean a tree?

If so, there are a few links here : http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12138128/Tree

eg. http://www.jstree.com/ or http://jquery.bassistance.de/treeview/demo/

Also, check out these questions:

- [How to create a menu tree using HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989829/how-to-create-a-menu-tree-using-html)
- [Turning an HTML select element into a tree with submenus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3208044/turning-an-html-select-element-into-a-tree-with-submenus)

Answer (score 1):

.NET has the TreeView control, which will accomplish what you've described.  The HTML it generates is pretty ugly, but it gets the job done.

There are lots of jQuery plugins that will also work.  You might have an easier time finding one if you search for "Tree" or "TreeView" instead of "Accordion".  I think "Accordion" implies a single-level structure.

Comment: thanks for the reply. yes, I am getting better results by searching for menu tree

Answer (score 0):

Found a couple you might want to look at. Not sure what your requirements as far as js or non js go though:

http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-accordion/ (apply a different class to distinuguidh multiple levels)

http://www.leigeber.com/2009/03/accordion/